# Is (int)$_GET['user_input'] safe?

Tags: php, security, user-input

Is it safe to assume that in

```
if (($i = (int)trim($_GET['user_input'])) != 0) {
    // do stuff with $i
}
```

`$i` can only ever be an integer?

---

**Edit:**

I now use:

```
if (ctype_digit($i = $_GET['user_input'])) {
    // do stuff with $i
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if `$_GET['user_input']` is 'a' as an example it's 0. (If the cast fails)

Comment: @Rizier123 Which is why I have `!= 0`. I want only integers different from zero.

Comment: Yes then your condition works! So your question answered?

Comment: $_GET['user_input'])) > 0

Comment: @what Made a answer and wrote an example with a few infos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your only question is if it's in any case a `int`, then is the answer :

Yes

But if the cast to int fails (e.g. input: `'a'`) `$i` is just `0`

Example:

Input/ Output:

```
4       ->  4
-5      -> -5
"14"    -> 15
"a"     ->  0
"!"     ->  0
array() ->  0
```

Side Note:

If the value is an array trim fails and you get an error

Comment: @what All things that are client site can the user manipulate! So all validation has to be server side! A user can even change a select list to a text filed

Answer (score 0):

**Check this**

```
if(stripslashes(trim($_GET['user_input']))) > 0){
//your code Here 
}
```

Comment: WRONG! If $_GET['user_input'] is negative it won't work!

Comment: This does not clean the input, which is the whole purpose of casting it as integer.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have CodeIgniter, so `Fatal error: Call to undefined function xss_clean() ...`.

Comment: use trim instead of xss_clean

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = intval($_GET['user_input']);
if ( $i != 0) {
    // do stuff with $i
}
```

check it's documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you check for integer, then

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['user_input']) && $_GET['user_input'] > 0) {
//your code
}
```

Comment: I don't want floating point numbers, or at least I want to cast them to some integer. $i must be full integers. If I use (int), then 1.2 turns into 1, which is acceptable (it would be better to be FALSE).

Comment: Ok, then you can use intval() function, example:                    echo intval(42);                      // 42
echo intval(4.2);                     // 4
echo intval('42');                    // 42
echo intval('+42');                   // 42

Comment: WRONG! If $_GET['user_input'] is negative it won't work!